# Conditional Formatting: Min Value Across Multiple Columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting

I have three columns--Order, Buy, and Craft--and want to identify the minimum value for the row.  In the image below, I identify the value in an additional column.  I want to avoid the need for the additional column by using conditional formatting to highlight the minimum value.

I have Googled the problem and tried a couple of formulas, but neither one seemed to work correctly.

Can anyone assist?

[image: ![Screenshot of formula issue]

Comment: You mean to say you want to highlight lowest value in each row ?

Comment: Yep you're right.

Edited : Thank you everyone for the help! :D

Answer (score 4):

[image]

I'm assuming that your data range is C3:E10.

- Select C3:E10.
- Write this formula as Formatting Rule.

  `=IF(C3<>"",C3=MIN($C3:$E3))`.
- Apply color format of your choice and finish with Ok.

**Additionally I would like to suggest the following, which is an optional:**

- If you want the formatting to stop when there are no values in the
  row adjust to, then write this formula as formatting Rule.

  `=AND(COUNT($C3:$E3)<>0,C3=Min($C3:$E3))`

**N.B.** *Adjust the cell address as per your need.*

Comment: Take it across the finish line by showing the result (including one or more blanks).  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234, if I'm not wrong you mean to say I've to add blanks in data range ?

Comment: The OP's example shows there can be blanks, so demonstrating how the formula handles them would be good (and instructive about how MIN handles them).

Comment: @fixer1234, nice suggestion, thanks, But I'm sure the blank rows between will not make any difference if blank rows are part of Applied to range. Or if you feel please edit the answer, will help me also.

Comment: I was referring to blank cells in the row like the OP's Mushroom Loaf example.  BTW, your count<>0 handles blank rows, but verify you don't have a typo.  I think you meant $C3:$E3 rather than the whole matrix.

Comment: @fixer1234, just now I've tested and in both cases it's working either $C3:$E10 or $C3:$E3. Thanks again :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78293/discussion-between-fixer1234-and-rajesh-s).

Answer (score 2):

Create a conditional format in CELL C3:

```
=AND(C3<>"",C3=MIN($C3:$E3))
```

Then apply this format to `C3:E50`

Change the 50 to which ever row you wish it to go down to.

Here you will not need to use the `MIN` column F

Comment: @fixer1234 good spot, amended formula